# Select an element with a specified class with parent in JQuery

Tags: jquery, class, find, parent

I don't know what's wrong, i have as follows:

```
<tr>
  <td><span class="idTask">1</span></td>               
  <td><span>Another Hello</span></td>                              
  <td><img class="delete" src="img/delete.png" alt="Edit" /></td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="" /></td>
</tr>
```

When i click a button a function calls to iterate through the all checked box for being delete, i need to retrieve the value from idTask, i'm trying to do as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $(".deleteAll").click( function(){
    var conf=confirm("Are you sure?");
    if(conf==true) {  
        $(':checkbox').each(function () {
        if(this.checked) {
            alert(($(this)).parent().find('.idTask').text());
        } 
        });
    }
    });
});
```

But doesn't work, with prev() or next() works, but is not for me an elegant way to do this, any suggestions for find a children element matching his class inside a parent to retrieve his value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent of the checkbox is `<td>` but not `<tr>`. You should better use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(".deleteAll").click(function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        $(":checkbox").each(function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                // --------------.-.-.-.-.-.-.
                //               v v v v v v v
                var id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".idTask").text();
                alert(id);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks VisioN! You save my day! I use before closest, but i was wrong giving "td" instead "tr" closest suppose to find the all elements that match with the checkbox in this case, and search for his childrens, right? I think i misunderstanding some concepts.

Comment: Easily speaking, `closest` finds the first element that matches the selector within all parents of your checkbox in the DOM tree. So in our case it will find the first `tr`.